# Optimal paths on terrain

Tags: matlab

This question may be asking for a lot, but I have a matrix which models terrain (ie it is a heightmap). I wondered if anyone knew of any functions etc to select two points on the terrain and find the optimal path between them based on the other height values of the cells?

I currently have functions which do this, but they are rather computationally expensive and I'd like to make this as speedy as possible.

If this question is quite simply farfetch'd then please let me know and I can stick with the computationally expensive functions and stop being fussy!

Thanks

Comment: I think that Simulated Annealing should be one of the faster algorithms for your kind of problem

Comment: Simulated annealing seems to be associated with finding maximums and minums of functions, whereas I just want the optimal path between two points

Comment: An optimal path is nothing more than a multi-dimensional function that you are trying to minimize